# Route using certain IP address

Tags: linux, routing

I have a server with two public IPs. Both IPs are added to `eth0` using `ip addr add`. Now I'd like to contact a server which uses IP address filtering. Only requests are allowed which use the second IP address. Is there are way to set this up using the standard `route` command in Linux? I guess that's not the case.

So the *only* solution I see right now: Setup a virtual device let's say `eth0:0` and bind the second IP address to it. Then I can reference the device in the `route` command.

*Edit:*
I can't use the second IP as primary one easily as this IP is used as failover IP.

Comment: Why route?  Why not setup a SNAT?  As in have iptables adjust the source address?

Comment: Good point. I'll look into this...

Comment: Whatever application you are connecting from should bind to the IP you want for it's outbound connection. It's not terribly common for user applications to support this, but many server and diagnostic programs do.

Answer (score 1):

You can always try:

```
# ip r add <dest server>/32 via <default gateway of second IP>
```

Answer (score 1):

INTERFACE=Device-Name for your second IP

HOSTNAME=Your target host

`route add -host $HOSTNAME dev $INTERFACE`